# Magento 2: How to Pass popup modal form data to the custom controller?

Tags: magento2, ajax, forms, modal-popup

I want to redirect to the custom controller on the Continue button in the popup modal form.

> **Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="test" id="test">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> **Vendor\Module\Controller\Guest\Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Guest;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * result page Factory
     *
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    protected $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->helper=$helper;
        $this->url=$context->getUrl();
        $this->responseFactory=$responseFactory;
        $this->customerSession=$customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost());
        exit();
        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Test Information'));
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

> **popup.phtml**

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="test_guestform">
        <?php echo __("test") ?>
    </a>
</li>

<div id="test-guest-popup-modal" style="display: none;" >
    <div class="message info notlogged" id="testGuest-form">
        <div class="test_guestNotice">
            <?php /* @noEscape */ echo __('You\'re not Logged in. Please add your Email-Address for test Order!') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form test-guest-form" action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'test/guest/index';?>" id="test-guest-form" method="post" data-hasrequired="* Required Fields" data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}' >
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey(); ?>" />
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span>Email Address</span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" title="Email" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"  value="" />
            </div>
            <span class="test-guest-error" style="display:none;color:red;font-size:13px;">* This is Required Field.</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function (data) {
                        var form_data = jQuery("#test-guest-form").serialize();
                        var email = jQuery("#email").val();
                        var Url = jQuery('#test-guest-form').attr('action');
                        // email.trim().match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/) == null
                        if (email == '') 
                        {
                            console.log("error");
                            jQuery(".test-guest-error").css("display","block");
                        }else{
                            jQuery(".test-guest-error").css("display","none");
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                dataType: "json",
                                url: Url,
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: form_data+"&isAjax=true",
                                success: function(response){
                                    var res = response;
                                    obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
                                    if (obj.success == "1") {
                                        console.log("success");
                                        window.location.href = Url;
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function(result){
                                    console.log('no response !');
                                }
                            });
                            this.closeModal();
                        }
                    }
                }],
                 /**
                 * Escape key press handler,
                 * close modal window
                 */
                escapeKey: function () {
                    if (this.options.isOpen && this.modal.find(document.activeElement).length ||
                        this.options.isOpen && this.modal[0] === document.activeElement) {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#test-guest-popup-modal'));
            $("#test_guestform").on('click',function(){
                $("#test-guest-popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

> I've tried above code but it's showing `no response` in console.

**Please let me know if anyone has any idea.**

Comment: did you get posted data in ajax in your controller?

Comment: no, actually it's not redirecting to the controller.

Comment: Have you checked your route name ? is this correct?

Comment: yes, it is fine.

Comment: Could you share your route and controler code.. did you get value in $block->getBaseUrl()  ?

Comment: yes I'm getting base url. http://127.0.01/magento_232/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102678/discussion-between-aravind-and-mohit-rane).